# parse php code as html using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just want to check what is possible using htaccess. During searching i found that htaccess have a power to parse php files as html and display php code into browser console. I want to ask is this possible using htaccess. if yes then any example of this.

Comment: htaccess doesn't "parse" anything. htaccess isn't a program. It's just a set of override directives for apache that apply to the contents of a particular directory. yes, what you want is possible, just put in a htaccess directive to force apache to treat .php files as text/plain instead of php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` does nothing, it only contains rules on how to handle some requests.

I think what you mean is a common extension that (by default) parses .php**s** files so they contain highlighting.

You can add this to your .htaccess to enable it for other file extensions as well:

> AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .your-file-extension

(this requires the PHP extension for Apache, but I think you already have that one)